# C macro adding to a typename

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to create a C macro, that given a typename will append `_info` to it, take the address of that and a call a function with it. Example code (doesn't work):

```
#define new(X) __new(&(X_info))

struct classInfo
{
    size_t size;
    void* (*constructor)(void* p);
};

void* __new(struct classInfo* info, ...)
{
    return info->constructor(malloc(info->size));
}

void* queue_constructor(void* p)
{
    return p;
}

typedef struct
{
    uint64_t data;
} queue_t;

const struct classInfo queue_t_info = { .size        = sizeof(queue_t),
                                        .constructor = &queue_constructor};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    queue_t* p = new(queue_t);
    return 0;
}
```

The preprocessor doesn't seem to want to expand X, as it's error'ing about an undefined symbol `X_info`. Not sure what I should change on the macro to fix this.

Comment: You shouldn't use leading underscore for your global identifiers, those are reserved for extensions by the compiler and standard library. I also would refrain from using C++ keywords (like `new`), as people coming from C++ background might find it confusing, and also some compilers really don't have a proper pure C mode (like MS Visual C++).

Comment: Good point, I'll use something else. Any particular ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the *token concatenation* feature of the preprocessor; otherwise it thinks that `X_info` is a token by itself:

```
#define new(X) __new(&(X ## _info))
```

The reason the preprocessor won't expand the `X` in `X_info` is that this would have created big problems if there actually was an identifier called `X_info` that you needed to refer to in the macro.

As a side note, there is also the *stringification* feature: if `X` is e.g. `Person`, `"X"` will remain `"X"`, while `#X` will expand to the string constant `"Person"`.